# 2D Fourier downsampling to even number of points gives incorrect modes in the last column

Tags: image-processing, fft, filters, python, sampling

I would like to downsample an image in the frequency domain to an even shape, similar to what is described in [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/64821/2d-fourier-downsampling). I have been able to do this successfully with a 1D signal to both an odd and even downsampled resolution. For an image, I can do this with 0 error when downsampling to an odd shape, but have run into issues with the modes in the last column when downsampling to an even shape.

As described in [this other post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85330/how-is-the-inverse-fourier-transform-of-a-hermitian-symmetric-input-efficiently), in a 1D signal, the first and final modes for an even number of sampling points must have 0 imaginary part, which is related to Hermitian symmetry. Thus, when filtering a 1D signal to a lower resolution, we can expect the corresponding modes will perfectly match the higher resolution, save for the imaginary part of the last mode:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import numpy as np

with cbook.get_sample_data('membrane.dat') as datafile:
    x = np.fromfile(datafile, np.float32)

print(f"x has shape {x.shape}")
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()

Fx = np.fft.rfft(x)

higher_resolution = len(x)
lower_resolution = 512
rate = higher_resolution / lower_resolution
highest_wavenumber = len(np.fft.rfftfreq(lower_resolution))
print(f"To reduce the signal from shape {higher_resolution} to shape {lower_resolution}, truncate Fx to first {highest_wavenumber} modes")

Fx_truncated = Fx[:highest_wavenumber] / rate
x_truncated = np.fft.irfft(Fx_truncated, n=lower_resolution) 
print(f'The shape of the truncated signal is {len(x_truncated)}')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, num=higher_resolution), x, label='full resolution')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, num=lower_resolution), x_truncated, color='red', label='truncated')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Ferror = Fx_truncated - np.fft.rfft(x_truncated)
print(f"The final mode of the truncated transform is {Fx_truncated[-1].round(3)}, and the final mode of the reconstructed transform is {np.fft.rfft(x_truncated)[-1].round(3)}")
plt.plot(Ferror.real, label='Real part error')
plt.title("Error on real and imaginary part")
plt.plot(Ferror.imag, label='Imaginary part error', color='red', linestyle='dashed')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
x has shape (12000,)

To reduce the signal from shape 12000 to shape 512, truncate Fx to first 257 modes
The shape of the truncated signal is 512
```

[image: full_versus_truncated1D]

```
The final mode of the truncated transform is (0.082+0.908j), and the final mode of the reconstructed transform is (0.082+0j)
```

[image: Ferror1d]

However, when trying to do the same thing with an image, the modes in the last column have differences in both their real and imaginary parts, whereas I would only expect an error in the imaginary part, as with the 1D case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import numpy as np

w, h = 256, 256
with cbook.get_sample_data('s1045.ima.gz') as datafile:
    image = datafile.read()
image = np.frombuffer(image, np.uint16).astype(float).reshape((w, h))
image = image / image.max()

plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.hot)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

Fx = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.rfft2(image), axes=0)
higher_resolution = len(image)
lower_resolution = 64
rate = higher_resolution / lower_resolution
lower_resolution_wavenumbers = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(lower_resolution) * lower_resolution)
lowest_wavenumber_y, highest_wavenumber_y = lower_resolution_wavenumbers.astype(int)[[0, -1]]
higher_resolution_wavenumbers = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(higher_resolution) * higher_resolution)
mid = higher_resolution // 2
assert higher_resolution_wavenumbers[mid] == 0
lowest_wavenumber_y_idx, highest_wavenumber_y_idx = mid + lowest_wavenumber_y, mid + highest_wavenumber_y
assert np.allclose(higher_resolution_wavenumbers[lowest_wavenumber_y_idx:highest_wavenumber_y_idx+1], lower_resolution_wavenumbers)
highest_wavenumber_x_idx = len(np.fft.rfftfreq(lower_resolution)) - 1

print(f"To reduce the signal from shape {higher_resolution,higher_resolution} to shape {lower_resolution,lower_resolution}, truncate Fx to modes {lowest_wavenumber_y},...,{highest_wavenumber_y} (indexed as {lowest_wavenumber_y_idx},...,{highest_wavenumber_y_idx}) along the y-axis and modes 0,...,{highest_wavenumber_x_idx} along the x-axis")
Fx_truncated = Fx[lowest_wavenumber_y_idx:highest_wavenumber_y_idx+1, :highest_wavenumber_x_idx+1] / (rate**2)
# Fx_truncated[:, 0] = Fx_truncated[:, 0].real
# Fx_truncated[:, -1] = Fx_truncated[:, -1].real
x_truncated = np.fft.irfft2(np.fft.ifftshift(Fx_truncated, axes=0), s=(lower_resolution, lower_resolution))

plt.imshow(x_truncated, cmap=plt.cm.hot)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

Fx_truncated_recontructed = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.rfft2(x_truncated), axes=0)
Ferror = Fx_truncated - Fx_truncated_recontructed
Ferror.real[Ferror.real == 0] = np.abs(Ferror.real[Ferror.real != 0]).min()
Ferror.imag[Ferror.imag == 0] = np.abs(Ferror.imag[Ferror.imag != 0]).min()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,10))
im = ax[0].imshow(np.log(np.abs(Ferror.real)), cmap=plt.cm.hot)
ax[0].set_title('Error on Real Part')
im = ax[1].imshow(np.log(np.abs(Ferror.imag)), cmap=plt.cm.hot)
ax[1].set_title('Error on Imaginary Part')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax.ravel().tolist(), orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: fullres2d]

```
To reduce the signal from shape (256, 256) to shape (64, 64), truncate Fx to modes -32,...,31 (indexed as 96,...,159) along the y-axis and modes 0,...,32 along the x-axis
```

[image]
[image: Ferror2d]

As suggested in [this other post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85330/how-is-the-inverse-fourier-transform-of-a-hermitian-symmetric-input-efficiently), I tried setting the imaginary part of the modes in the last and first columns to 0 with

```
Fx_truncated[:, 0] = Fx_truncated[:, 0].real
Fx_truncated[:, -1] = Fx_truncated[:, -1].real
```

However, this gave really bad results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried setting the imaginary part of the modes in the last and first columns to 0

The first column doesn't need to be all real. It is only the value at frequency (0,0) (the DC component) that is expected to be real. And it should already be real to start with.

The last "column" in the RFFT direction (horizontally here) needs to be real. And the first "column" in the FFT direction (vertically here) needs to be real. Both these "columns" (using quotes to reinforce that the direction is not necessarily vertical) correspond to the Nyquist frequency and need to be real-valued for the inverse transform to produce a real-valued image. The IRFFT function ignores the imaginary components for these elements. So if you want to match what `irfft2` sees, then you need to

```
Fx_truncated[:, -1].imag = 0  # RFFT direction
Fx_truncated[0, :].imag = 0   # FFT direction
```

But setting the imaginary component of these elements to 0 changes both the magnitude and phase of these frequency components. Changing their phase could be highly visible (if the components have a significant amplitude). So this is a bad thing to do.

It is much better to set these elements to 0:

```
Fx_truncated[:, -1] = 0
Fx_truncated[0, :] = 0
```

It is better to completely remove a frequency component than to shift it. We're removing all of the higher frequency components any way, removing one more won't be all that noticeable.

I now see `np.max(np.abs(Ferror))` being around 6.36e-14.

Comment: A small thing: 'And the first "column" in the FFT direction (vertically here) needs to be real.' possibly should have "row" in place of "column".

A more interesting note is that if I omit `Fx_truncated[0, :] = 0`, the only large error is on the mode indexed as `0,0`. Instead doing `Fx_truncated[0, 0] = Fx_truncated[0, 0].real` gives an error which is about equal as in the `Fx_truncated[0, :] = 0` case, but it preserves the real part of the modes `Fx_truncated[0, 1:]`

Comment: @JacobHelwig I put “column” in quotes to make the statement more generic. In your case it is a row, but in some other nD RFFT implementation it could have a different orientation.

Comment: @JacobHelwig Maybe we can get away with removing fewer frequency components, I haven’t analyzed it very precisely. I would just remove all the frequency components at Nyquist because they are ambiguous anyway.

Comment: I would like to understand this better, so please correct me: say we have a 1D signal sampled at 64 points. The Nyquist frequency, which is the frequency of the wave numbered 31, is the highest frequency which we can uniquely identify in this signal. If we try to detect the wave numbered 32, aliasing occurs, which means that there are multiple DFT coefficients for mode 32 which could produce a function that perfectly interpolates our sample points ("they are ambiguous anyway"). In my case, doing `Fx_truncated[0, 0] = Fx_truncated[0, 0].real` leads to aliasing of the modes `Fx_truncated[0, 1:]`

Comment: @JacobHelwig Aliasing happens only when sampling. Your input is already sampled, so if there was any aliasing, then it's done and can't be undone. We can't even know if it happened. When you have an even number of samples, then the FFT has one bin *at* the Nyquist frequency. A properly sampled signal has only frequencies *below* the Nyquist frequency. The FFT outputs frequencies k=0..N-1. At k=N/2 we have the Nyquist frequency. The FFT bins above it (which are not computed by the RFFT) are for sine components that alias to lower frequencies, and combine with those lower frequencies [continued]

Comment: [continued] The element at k=N-1 aliases to k=1, and combines with that frequency to produce a real-valued wave. This is where the symmetry comes from. We often think of k=N-1 as having a frequency of -1, but in the Discrete Fourier Transform it's not defined that way. ---- So in your case of N=64, k=32 is the Nyquist frequency. If the signal had been properly bandlimited before sampling, this bin would be 0. This is why we can and should zero out this frequency bin when downsampling. If you don't, you are not really causing any aliasing, because we're not sampling a continuous signal. [contd]

Comment: [continued] What happens with this frequency is that we lose its phase. Imagine sampling a sine wave exactly twice per period. The sampled signal will be a, -a, a, -a, a, -a, ... no matter what the original phase was. "a" can be any value, including negative, so we can only distinguish -sin from +sin, not sin from cos. We also don't know the original magnitude of the frequency component, as we probably are not sampling the peaks of the signal. If you're unlucky, you sample at the zero crossings and get a magnitude of 0. So this signal can be sampled, but not preserved. It's the odd one out.

Comment: @JacobHelwig The Nyquist frequency aliases onto itself, messing up its own magnitude and resetting its own phase.